# Exchange 2010 queue viewer not working in Exchange Management console

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, powershell, exchange-2010

I recently agreed to help my works network admin with the exchange 2010 server (seeing as I have experience in 2016 which were migrating to at the end of the year), but when trying to administer it, [I get this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7DZS.png). This happens when I try to open queue viewer, or message viewer. I have the same exchange privileges that the network admin has but when he tries there is no issue. I also can not run a handful of cmdlets in the exchange management shell. Unless there is a certain privilege I do know about I don't know the issue. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Alright after a lot of digging I found out that Active directory groups is not the same as exchange server roles. So to fix this you have to go to your EMC -> toolbox -> Role Based Access Control User Editor -> log in then options -> See all options -> Manage my organization -> Roles and Auditing -> then add yourself (or have an admin) to Organization Management role. Simple but annoying.